# Python using XML API output with lxml.objectify

Tags: python, api, lxml, objectify

I have a couple of classes which use an API of one internal subsystem. We parse and use it's responses with lxml.objectify to go through the nodes with object.property syntax.

But the problem is that the code becomes really cluttered and non-pythonic since in some cases, if some property of the object does not exist, API just do not return the whole xml node related to this property & sub-properties.

This results in the code like:

```
if hasattr(object,"property"):
    if hasattr(object.property,"subproperty"):
        etc...
```

Is there any pythonic way to do things like that? or just some good practices.
Checking if everysingle property exists before accessing it becomes a headache, maybe it is possible just to return None in case it does not exist?